# Xpath with wildcards between id and divs?

Tags: html, xpath, wildcard

I try to enter data in a table using Robot Framework. The table has an ID, but it changes every time I load the page (it is some kind of UUID) so I can't use it as "anchor" for my xpath. However there is a heading for this table that seems reasonable to start with that has a fixed ID. Inbetween the heading and the table there are a couple of divs. So something like this (some mix of pseudo code and what I get when I copy selector and xpath in Chrome) to get to the first cell in the first line of the table:

```
//*[@id="heading"] (a bunch of divs) /*[@id="random string of letters"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]
```

I would like to write an xpath that looked something like this

```
//*[@id="heading"] [wildcard for the random ID and divs] /div[3]/div/div/div[2]
```

How do I write this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only one element inside the "header" contains an id attribute you could use

`//*[@id="heading"]//*[@id]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]`

If there are more than one element with id attribute you need something more, eg if it contains a certain tag

`//*[@id="heading"]//*[contains(@id, "tag")]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]`

or (if using xpath 2.0) and only this @id contains an uuid within the heading

`//*[@id="heading"]//*[matches(@id,"[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}")]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]`

Otherways you will have to try to find something unique (within the context of "heading") to start the `div[3]/div/div/div[2]` search (if you are lucky `div[3]/div/div/div[2]` is unique enough.